# Localization of Launch Screen XIB not working properly

Tags: ios, localization, xib, splash-screen, launch-screen

In my app i use Launch screen xibs for the splash screens with six different local languages. Localization works fine. App takes proper launch xib for proper language at its time of install, but i changed language after install and launched app again, Launch xib remains same for the old language.